# TypeError: message.guild.channels.filter is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a Discord bot using discord.js for a server. While working on a command to display the server's information, I came across an error.

Here's the code:

```
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const colors = require('../colors.json');

const date = new Date();
dateFormat(date, 'dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT');

exports.run = async (client, message, args, ops) => {

    const millis = new Date().getTime() - message.guild.createdAt.getTime();
    const days = millis / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

    const owner = message.guild.owner.user || {};

    const verificationLevels = ['None ,(^.^),', 'Low ┬─┬ ノ( ゜-゜ノ)', 'Medium ヽ(ຈل͜ຈ)ﾉ︵ ┻━┻ ', 'High (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻', 'Extreme ┻━┻彡 ヽ(ಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻'];

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL)
                    .setFooter(`requested by ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`, message.author.avatarURL)
                    .setColor(colors.cyan)
                    .addField('Server Name', message.guild.name, true)
                    .addField('Server ID', message.guild.id, true)
                    .addField('Owner',`${owner.username + "#" + owner.discriminator || '� Owner not found...'}`,true)
                    .addField('Owner ID', `${owner.id || '� Owner not found...'}`,true)
                    .addField('Created On',`${dateFormat(message.guild.createdAt)}`, true)
                    .addField('Days Since Creation', `${days.toFixed(0)}`, true)
                    .addField('Region',`${message.guild.region}`, true)
                    .addField('Verification Level',`${verificationLevels[message.guild.verificationLevel]}`,true)
                    .addField('Text Channels',`${message.guild.channels.filter(m => m.type === 'text').size}`,true)
                    .addField('Voice Channels',`${message.guild.channels.filter(m => m.type === 'voice').size}`,true)
                    .addField('Member Count',`${message.guild.members.filter(m => m.presence.status !== 'offline').size} / ${message.guild.memberCount}`, true)
                    .addField('Roles',`${message.guild.roles.size}`,true)
                    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

And here's the error:

```
(node:17432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.channels.filter is not a function
    at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\brigh\Desktop\XontavsBot\commands\serverinfo.js:29:73)
    at Client.client.on (C:\Users\brigh\Desktop\XontavsBot\index.js:30:21)
    at Client.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\brigh\Desktop\XontavsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\brigh\Desktop\XontavsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\brigh\Desktop\XontavsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\brigh\Desktop\XontavsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:435:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\brigh\Desktop\XontavsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\brigh\Desktop\XontavsBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
(node:17432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17432) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

If anybody knows what the problem is, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Discord.js v12, many things like `Guild#channels` got [turned into a manager](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache). `Guild#channels` is now a [`ChannelManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager), so to get the collection of channels use `message.guild.channels.cache`. For example:

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.filter(m => m.type === 'text').size
```